# How do I add a header in each of my text files based on the first two words of the filename?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a folder with several hundred .txt files with numbers. The files are named in a format word1_word2_word3_word4.txt. The words are different for each of the .txt files.

I would like to add a header to each of those text files based on the filename such that the header is of the format:

> '>c_word1_word2'

Is there a way to do this for all the .txt files using the command line or a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) using some [*parameter expansion*](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.) *builtins* :

```
for i in *.txt; do j="${i%_*}"; sed "1i >c_${j%_*}" "$i"; done
```

### Output :

```
$ ls -1
word1_word2_word3_word4.txt
word2_word2_word3_word4.txt
word3_word2_word3_word4.txt
$ cat word1_word2_word3_word4.txt
foo
bar
base
$ for i in *.txt; do j="${i%_*}"; sed -i "1i >c_${j%_*}" $i; done
$ cat word1_word2_word3_word4.txt
>c_word1_word2
foo
bar
base
$
```

[image: warning] `-i` switch edit the file *in place*

Answer (score 1):

This is just an alternative to Gilles' answer, using a regular expression

```
for f in *.txt; do
    if [[ $f =~ ^([^_]+_[^_]+) ]]; then
        sed -i "1i>c_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "$f"
    fi
done
```